# How do you access the individual elements of a glsl mat4?

Tags: glsl

Is it possible to access the individual elements of a glsl mat4 type matrix? How?

Comment: -1: This is easily looked up by [reading the GLSL specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/), which is a very readable document.

Comment: Funnily enough the information is _not_ in the linked reference

Comment: There is a section entitled "Matrix Components" in all of the GLSL specifications. In GL 4.3, that's section 5.6.

Comment: Oh great.  Putting an answer in now, let's see how many hits and upvotes this question gets over the next few years.

Comment: Betting "Famous question" in 2 years.

Comment: @bobobobo famous question already? :P

Comment: @LukeB. dunno how it was in 2014, but currently it has 14562 views, which is more than enough for _Famous question_ badge.

Comment: "very readable document" is heavily opinionated, IMO. No spec is "very readable", as specs contains 99% information that you don't need and never will, unless you are designer of the spec.

Comment: +1 because searching for the problem on duckduckgo brought me straight here where I found an immediate answer.  If you hadn't posted this here, I'd have had to waste time searching for the spec and wading through it to find the answer.  So thanks.  :)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The Section 5.6 of the GLSL reference manual says you can access `mat4` array elements using `operator[][]` style syntax in the following way:

```
mat4 m;
m[1] = vec4(2.0); // sets the second column to all 2.0
m[0][0] = 1.0; // sets the upper left element to 1.0
m[2][3] = 2.0; // sets the 4th element of the third column to 2.0
```

Remember, OpenGL defaults to **column major matrices**, which means access is of the format `mat[col][row]`.  In the example, `m[2][3]` sets the 4th ROW (index 3) of the 3rd COLUMN (index 2) to 2.0.  In the example `m[1]=vec4(2.0)`, it is setting an entire column at once (because `m[1]` refers to column #2, when only ONE index is used it means that COLUMN. `m[1]` refers to the SECOND COLUMN VECTOR).

Comment: You can also use m[1].xyzw.

Comment: Column or row is pretty meaningless. More important: is the translation component of the matrix in (m[3][0],m[3][1],m[3][2]) or in (m[0][3],m[1][3],m[2][3]) ?

Comment: What do you mean by `defaults to`? Is there an option to switch to row major matrices?

Comment: mat[col][row] is more intuitive imho as those "parameters" always looked like x,y positions to me .. I think default mathematics writing mat[row][col] -> mat[y][x] is one of the biggest fails in mathematics .... (IMHO of course :)

Comment: well it s just a matter of transpose .. i don"t see any fuss about it..

Comment: @Ruslan yes, the layout(row_major) specifier.

Comment: @Buksy its the annoying fact that sometimes we use matrices to represent lists of points; where column major makes sense; and other times we use use matrices as lists of transformations, where row major makes sense. then you have the annoying property that to turn a point to a translation from origin to point, you need to set fourth column of an identity matrix to the points xyzw. there's no winning here; you will fconfuse the cpu no matter what you choose.

Comment: What are those float values?? How can we use them, or what do they change?

Comment: @LukeB. For future users like myself, to use swizzling (m[1].xyzw), `#define GLM_FORCE_SWIZZLE` has to be set (see [link](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/manual.md#-214-glm_force_swizzle-enable-swizzle-operators)). But it makes building the code slower.